# How to expand <cfile> if it has an @ in the path?

Tags: filesystem

I'm using arch linux and nvim. Everything is up to date.

I have a dir path `/home/user/name@web_address.com/144_p/data-dir-2/data_structure_here`

`gf` does not open the dir structure becasue `@` is present.

So instead in `.vimrc` I tried this
`:nnoremap gO :!xdg-open <cfile><CR>`
it works with files without `@` in the path, opening them with the default associated application, but the same hurdle exists, it does not open files with `@` in the path.
It only captures the bit of the path after `@` if the cursor is placed after the `@`,
and only captures the bit of the path before the `@` if the cursor is placed before the `@`.

I also tried
`let cfile=expand('<cfile>') | normal! gf cfile`
but that also does not work and captures only path parts as described in the remap above.

I have also tried using this command (see `:tab help isfname`) to include the `@` in the included character set as follows
`set isfname+="@"`
and this one
`set isfname+="@-@"`
to set things up before using the above commands, to make sure `@` is included as an available expression.

Comment: @maxim-kim thanks. I've updated the question to reflect my being a linux user. I also just tried `set isfname+=64`, didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set isfname+=@-@` should do the trick.

What you have tried `set isfname+="@-@"` also adds `"` which is not what you want. Help topic has it in quotes to separate from the rest of the text:

```
To include '@' itself use "@-@".
```

But `set` doesn't work this way (although with `let &isfname .= ",@-@"` it might work)

Comment: thank you. I wasn't looking at the `"`s and was going bananas in the process. Appreciated, thank you